# What is Swift doing behind the scenes when I add a target to a UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.handleButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

@objc private func handleButton(sender: UIButton!)
{
}
```

I'm still starting out with Swift, so this might be kind of basic, but what is going on with the `@objc` keyword, the underscore in `MyClass.handleButton(_:)`, and the exclamation after handleButton's argument? I gather that the old framework is in obj-c and that Swift is linking against it in some way, but I don't get the syntax. Is there a better way to set up a button programmatically in swift? Wouldn't swift be slower than obj-c in this case since it is layered on top of it?

Comment: `@objc` is an attribute. `handleButton(_:)` is a reference to a function. `UIButton!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional type.

Comment: `@obj-c` exposes private methods to obj-c. You wouldn't have to use it if your action was not private. Is there a reason it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going on with the @objc keyword?

The `action` parameter of `addTarget` is a `Selector`, which you can think of as a pointer to an Objective-C function.  In order to get a selector for a function, this function must be visible to `Objective-C` because it will be called by Apple's frameworks which are written in Objective-C.  There are two ways to do this: 1) either your class must be a subclass of `NSObject` or inherit from a class that inherits from `NSObject` (like `UIViewController`), or 2) you need to add the `@objc` attribute to the Swift function to expose the Swift method to Objective-C.

> the underscore in MyClass.handleButton(_:)?

The underscore represents the first argument to `handleButton`.  In Objective-C, the first parameter isn't named, so this is represented in Swift with `_` which is a wildcard meaning the parameter isn't named.

`MyClass.handleButton(_:)` specifies a function called `handleButton` that is defined in the class `MyClass` that takes one parameter.

If your `handleButton` had taken two parameters, like this:

```
@objc func handleButton(button: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
}
```

then the selector would have been `#selector(MyClass.handleButton(_:forEvent:))` showing that `handleButton` takes two arguments with the second named `forEvent`.

You can get away with specifying less than the full name when you specify the selector.  You can leave off the class name:

```
#selector(handleButton(_:))
```

and the compiler will look in your current class for the function.

If there is only the one `handleButton` function in your class (it is not overloaded), you can even leave off the argument specification:

```
#selector(handleButton)
```

> the exclamation after handleButton's argument?

```
@objc private func handleButton(sender: UIButton!)
{
}
```

Here, `UIButton!` is an *implicitly unwrapped optional* which means it is an optional that you can use without having to unwrap it (with `!`).  This allows a caller to pass `nil` instead of a reference to a `UIButton`, but that would of course crash anytime you tried to use `sender`.

There is no need for this to be an optional.  You will always be passed a `UIButton`, so get rid of the unnecessary `!`.

> Is there a better way to set up a button programmatically in Swift?

Not really, other than the shortcuts for the selector that I already mentioned.

> Wouldn't Swift be slower than obj-c in this case since it is layered on top of it?

You are interfacing to the Objective-C runtime.  Apple engineers are smart and work to make this fast and efficient.  The efficiency of this isn't something you should worry about, especially for a user interface method that will only be called when the user presses a button (i.e. not millions of times a second).